# using selenium htmlunit with load tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, htmlunit

Has anyone used HTML unit with TestNG invocation count and thread pool size? I drive all my Selenium2 tests with TestNG and have been playing around with running HtmlUnit tests in multiple threads as a light load test.

It seems to work almost too easy so I'm wondering what's the catch? Has anyone tried it?

Comment: This might sound like a silly question but are you sure they are all running?
I pressume you see the log messages from all the users running?
How long are you running your test for, how many threads and how many itirations per thread if relevant?